# Why this table's last column is too wide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handsontable

I have a data set which i'm displaing with handsontable library as a table. Problem is, my table's last column is too wide eventhough i didn't make any specification for that. Below you can see my html - css - javascript.
Also when i scroll table, first column stops being bold.

This is how it looks:
[image]
How can i fix these issues?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
        <script src="http://warpech.github.io/jquery-handsontable/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://warpech.github.io/jquery-handsontable/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://warpech.github.io/jquery-handsontable/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://warpech.github.io/jquery-handsontable/demo/css/samples.css?20140401">

        <style type="text/css">
            body {background: white; margin: 20px;}
            h2 {margin: 20px 0;}
            .zebraStyle > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td {background: #e0e0d1;}
            .firstRowStyle > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td {font-weight: Bold; text-align:center;} /*
            .firstColumnStyle > tbody > tr:eq(1) {font-weight: Bold;} */
        </style>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var arr= [["", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014(YTD)"], ["Ferrari", "23.799.245.586", "24.690.793.476", "25.637.877.928", "26.189.313.420", "26.759.521.361", "28.238.790.068", "7.363.270.000", "2.527.936.616"], ["Alfa Romeo", "948.840.165", "1.035.394.421", "1.207.130.829", "1.432.940.401", "1.460.089.088", "1.637.243.070", "425.353.290", "137.777.306"], ["Aston Martin", "1.224.273.741", "1.171.484.355", "1.182.773.083", "1.219.699.570", "1.199.141.138", "1.224.624.821", "284.496.087", "96.903.916"], ["Renault", "483.793.987", "466.042.354", "456.537.683", "452.938.678", "533.421.162", "760.272.188", "216.715.015", "75.310.147"], ["Mercedes Benz", "789.262.256", "772.821.174", "773.167.187", "843.102.608", "901.922.932", "888.354.063", "218.907.883", "73.654.116"], ["BMW", "1.015.470.711", "959.962.514", "950.339.914", "872.787.810", "808.073.299", "792.529.238", "193.279.429", "67.888.380"], ["Bugatti", "117.987.733", "150.848.338", "165.913.066", "229.880.712", "254.621.690", "314.049.044", "126.315.485", "65.706.666"], ["Volvo", "300.737.769", "366.089.550", "437.732.938", "496.374.653", "583.436.131", "688.728.665", "189.419.815", "62.063.316"], ["Lamborghini", "1.145.266.348", "1.190.619.961", "978.255.422", "739.009.730", "688.060.328", "707.948.227", "191.463.900", "60.533.498"], ["Maserati", "812.817.727", "880.551.309", "851.913.877", "634.843.167", "629.542.913", "590.023.385", "167.015.651", "59.506.729"], ["Audi", "701.284.022", "718.701.862", "700.197.497", "684.531.574", "677.868.130", "684.122.911", "173.536.385", "57.995.362"]];

            $(document).ready( function(){
                $('#myTable').handsontable({
                    data: arr,
                    minSpareRows: 1,
                    contextMenu: true,
                    readOnly: true,
                    fixedColumnsLeft: 1
                });
                $('#myTable').find('table').addClass('zebraStyle');
                $('#myTable').find('table').addClass('firstRowStyle');
                $('#myTable').find('td:first-child').css("font-weight", "bold");
                //$('.handle').css("left","200px"); // this line sets position of scroll bar
                //$('#myTable').scrollLeft(200);

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myTable" class="handsontable" style="width: 750px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:silver"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

After I updated my javascript from Volkan Ulukut's answer, this is my javascript:

```
    var arr= [["", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014(YTD)"], ["Ferrari", "23.799.245.586", "24.690.793.476", "25.637.877.928", "26.189.313.420", "26.759.521.361", "28.238.790.068", "7.363.270.000", "2.527.936.616"], ["Alfa Romeo", "948.840.165", "1.035.394.421", "1.207.130.829", "1.432.940.401", "1.460.089.088", "1.637.243.070", "425.353.290", "137.777.306"], ["Aston Martin", "1.224.273.741", "1.171.484.355", "1.182.773.083", "1.219.699.570", "1.199.141.138", "1.224.624.821", "284.496.087", "96.903.916"], ["Renault", "483.793.987", "466.042.354", "456.537.683", "452.938.678", "533.421.162", "760.272.188", "216.715.015", "75.310.147"], ["Mercedes Benz", "789.262.256", "772.821.174", "773.167.187", "843.102.608", "901.922.932", "888.354.063", "218.907.883", "73.654.116"], ["BMW", "1.015.470.711", "959.962.514", "950.339.914", "872.787.810", "808.073.299", "792.529.238", "193.279.429", "67.888.380"], ["Bugatti", "117.987.733", "150.848.338", "165.913.066", "229.880.712", "254.621.690", "314.049.044", "126.315.485", "65.706.666"], ["Volvo", "300.737.769", "366.089.550", "437.732.938", "496.374.653", "583.436.131", "688.728.665", "189.419.815", "62.063.316"], ["Lamborghini", "1.145.266.348", "1.190.619.961", "978.255.422", "739.009.730", "688.060.328", "707.948.227", "191.463.900", "60.533.498"], ["Maserati", "812.817.727", "880.551.309", "851.913.877", "634.843.167", "629.542.913", "590.023.385", "167.015.651", "59.506.729"], ["Audi", "701.284.022", "718.701.862", "700.197.497", "684.531.574", "677.868.130", "684.122.911", "173.536.385", "57.995.362"]];
    function firstRowRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
        Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
        td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }


    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('#myTable').handsontable({
            data: arr,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            contextMenu: true,
            readOnly: true,
            fixedColumnsLeft: 1
            cells: function (row, col, prop) {
                var cellProperties = {};
                if (col === 0) {
                    cellProperties.renderer = firstRowRenderer; // uses function directly
                }
                return cellProperties;
            }
        });
        $('#myTable').find('table').addClass('zebraStyle');
        $('#myTable').find('table').addClass('firstRowStyle');
        $('#myTable').find('td:first-child').css("font-weight", "bold");
        //$('#myTable').find('td').css("width","50px");
        //$('.handle').css("left","200px"); // this line sets position of scroll bar
        //$('#myTable').scrollLeft(200);

    });
```

Comment: you specified a width for the table, which enforces the sum of all columns to be 750. first columns stretch according to their content and the last one gets all the remaining width for himself.

Comment: how can i share out this remaining width to all columns?

Comment: well you could specify a width for every column with `td {width: 150px;}`.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/FACnJ/) for this :) .. the current answers don't seem to work here....

Comment: At first glance I thought setting `table-layout:fixed` to the table would work, but after inspecting the above fiddle it seems that it is already set. hmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add column width to your css:

```
td {width: 150px;}
```

to make the first column bold (and stick with it) you need to use cells property

```
$('#myTable').handsontable({
    data: arr,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    contextMenu: true,
    readOnly: true,
    fixedColumnsLeft: 1,
    cells: function (row, col, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};
        if (col === 0) {
          cellProperties.renderer = firstRowRenderer; //uses function directly
        }
        return cellProperties;
      }        
});
```

and the function for it:

```
function firstRowRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
  td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FACnJ/1/)

Comment: added solution for bold issue.

Comment: eventhough it works when i take all code from your js fiddle. It's not working when i updated my file with your code. You can see latest version of javascript from my initial post

Comment: missing comma here: `fixedColumnsLeft: 1`

Comment: i'm sorry, that was so silly of me to miss. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

add width to table

#myTable table{ width:100%; }

Answer (score -1):

you need to use percentage when adjusting width of element

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: My aim is not REPUTATION. I tried to give an advice. this is not an answer for the question this is an advice. because you must not use widht with the actual number, always you must use percentage. if you read again my answe I wrote "element" table or whatever. But must be used with percentage.